# How can I optimize the arara password program?

Tags: programming, arara, ghostscript, ps2pdf

I have written the following (runable) `arara`-program, which creates a password-locked `pdf` with adjustable prohibited access rights:

`secure.yaml`

```
!config
# GhostScript-ps2pdf password-security rule for arara
# version: 0.1b
# requires arara 3.0+
identifier: secure
name: Secure
command: <arara> @{program} -sOwnerPassword=@{ownerpw} -sUserPassword=@{userpw} -dEncryptionR=@{encryptionmethode} -dKeyLength=@{keylength} -dPermissions=@{permission} @{getBasename(file)}.pdf @{outputpath}@{getBasename(file)}@{nameaffix}.pdf
arguments:
- identifier: program
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.program}
  default: ps2pdf
- identifier: ownerpw
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.ownerpw}
  default: aaa
- identifier: userpw
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.userpw}
  default: bbb
- identifier: encryptionmethode
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.encryptionmethode}
  default: 3
- identifier: keylength
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.keylength}
  default: 128
- identifier: permission
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.permission}
  default: 0
- identifier: nameaffix
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.nameaffix}
  default: _sec
- identifier: outputpath
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.outputpath}
  default: C:\Secret\
```

I would like to change, the last both `identifier` s.

**1. Problem "`nameaffix`"**

Without the `ouputpath`-Option, there will be created a file `jobname_sec.pdf` per default in the same working folder.

I would like to have an option like `%arara: secure: {nameaffix: false}`, so there would be generated a "secured"file `jobname.pdf`, that means, the the "unsecured" file will be 'overwritten'.

---

## Edit 1:

So, I think the first problem is not a problem, because:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% #arara: secure: { userpw: foo } 
% #arara: secure: { userpw: foo , nameaffix: -mostsecret } 
% #arara: secure: { userpw: foo , nameaffix: "" }

% in this order:
% <"nothing">  yields: jobname_sec.pdf, the default
% <nameaffix: -mostsecret> yields jobname-mostsecret.pdf
% <nameaffix: "">  yields jobname.pdf; but a different outputpath is needed!!!

\documentclass{article}       
\begin{document}
\section{My very secret Text}
......
\end{document}
```

---

**2. Problem "`outputpath`"**

How can I have this option as a pure optional parameter? That means:
`%arara: secure: {...}` If there is *no*  `... outputpath: C:/...` declared, the same working folder will be used for writing the "secured" file.

I hope, I have explained my problems understandable ;) Thank you for reading and for your interest.

---

## Edit 2:

For the 2nd problem, I think something like:

```
- identifier: outputpath
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.outputpath}
  default: <arara> @{ getDirname(file) }
```

is needed. **But this could not be completely right, because:**

In the case

```
% #arara: secure: { userpw: foo , outputpath: \SecrectDocuments\TodaysSecretDocuments }
```

an 'outputpath' was used (with a correct file inside).

**But:**

In the case

```
% arara: secure: { userpw: foo }
```

that means, without `outputpath`, a file named `nulljobname_sec.pdf` was created in the working folder. How can I erase  this prefix '**null**'?

---

**PS: Improvement suggestions / ideas in general are welcome too!**

*PPS:* I forgot, for testing arara-secure, use the following MWE for example:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: secure: { userpw: foo , permission: 0 } 

\documentclass{article}       
\begin{document}
\section{My very secret Text}
......
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now you are here ;-)

Comment: On TeXwelt.de they said, I should go to the authors on problems with arara. BTW: You could use the program in the answer for the official rule-collection, if you want.

Comment: I've rolled back an edit here: just a title really isn't likely to cover things here!

Comment: Ok. ________________________________________

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry, I searched for things, which was not really needed.

It works as wished and I like it and I like arara - and I hope you too :()

Note that very tiny changing.

```
!config
# GhostScript-ps2pdf password-security rule for arara
# version: 0.2b
# requires arara 3.0+
identifier: secure
name: Secure
command: <arara> @{program} -sOwnerPassword=@{ownerpw} -sUserPassword=@{userpw} -dEncryptionR=@{encryptionmethode} -dKeyLength=@{keylength} -dPermissions=@{permission} "@{getBasename(file)}.pdf" "@{outputpath}@{outputfilename}@{nameaffix}.pdf"
arguments:
- identifier: program
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.program}
  default: ps2pdf
- identifier: ownerpw
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.ownerpw}
  default: aaa
- identifier: userpw
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.userpw}
  default: bbb
- identifier: encryptionmethode
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.encryptionmethode}
  default: 3
- identifier: keylength
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.keylength}
  default: 128
- identifier: permission
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.permission}
  default: 0
- identifier: outputpath
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.outputpath}
- identifier: outputfilename
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.outputfilename}
  default: <arara> @{getBasename(file)}
- identifier: nameaffix
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.nameaffix}
  default: _sec
```

**(Please change your own defaults for userpw and ownerpw ;) )**

**Usage:**

```
%#########################################
%##### %arara: secure ##########################
%#########################################
%# PARAMETERS:
%# See   http://svn.ghostscript.com/ghostscript/trunk/gs/doc/Ps2pdf.htm
%# for further informations.
%
%# program: ps2pdf      (by default)
%
%# ownerpw: <OwnerPasswort>
%#  aaa     (by default)
%
%# userpw: <UserPasswort>
%#  bbb (by default)
%
%# encryptionmethode: <number>
%# 2 or 3 (default)
%
%# keylength: <number>
%: 40, 48, ... , 128 (default)
%
%# permission: <number>
%# => The sum of following numbers ---> allows
%# 0 ----------> all rights prohibited  (default)
%# 4    --> printing
%# 8    --> modifying
%# 16   --> copying contents
%# 32   --> adding / changing text annotations
%# 256  --> filling in (existing) formulary fields 
%# 512  --> extracting text / graphics
%# 1024 --> assembling the document
%# 2048 --> adding / changing text annotations
%# -1 ----------> all rights permitted
%
%# nameaffix: <text>
%# _sec (by default)
%#########################################


% arara: pdflatex
% arara: secure: { userpw: foo , permission: 0 } 

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{yellow!50}

\begin{document}
\section{My very secret Text}
......
\end{document}
```

**Some examples.**

**a1)** In the working folder a file with special userpasswort shall be generated, the ownerpasswort shall get it's default-value.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: secure: { userpw: foo } 

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{My very secret Text}
......
\end{document}
```

=> jobname_sec.pdf

**a2)** ... in addition there should be generated a special name-prefix.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: secure: { userpw: foo , nameaffix: -most_secret} 

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{My very secret Text}
......
\end{document}
```

=> jobname-most_secret.pdf

**b)** A file with same name (`jobname.pdf`) shall be generated in a special path (this is compulsive, becausse the original has to be overwritten, else).

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: secure: { userpw: foo , outputpath: 'C:\SecretDocuments\TodaysSecretDocuments\' , nameaffix: ''}  

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{My very secret Text}
......
\end{document}
```

=> `C:\SecretDocuments\TodaysSecretDocuments\jobname.pdf`

`nameaffix: ''` erases the parameter-value.

**c)** Feel free, to test some other parameters; ask, if there are problemes with it.